# WPF/XAML Style set Property for child items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, styles

I working on a XAML style for my controls.
The code below is for setting the color of a stackpanel. It works fine but there is something else I want to do. If the trigger is activated I want to set the font color for all child items inside the stackpanel.

At the moment I only have textblocks inside the stackpanel and I know I could easily create a separate style for a textbock. But if this style is triggered it will only affect ONE and not ALL textblocks.
But I want to change all items inside the stackpanel as soon as I got a mouseover trigger for the panel.

Is this even possible in XAML or do I have to code a regular event?

```
<Style x:Key="XStack" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="SkyBlue" Offset="6"/>                    
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- Trigger-->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your trigger:

`<Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>`

Answer (score 3):

Like Olle said, you can set the attached property `TextElement.Foreground` to a custom value. For a child control/UI node in the visual tree, if the property is not set, WPF will walk up the UI hierarchy till it finds a value and use it. *This means that all child controls can share a property value defined at the parent level.*

This should work for all TextBlocks... however if your StackPanel contained a TextBox, its text color wouldn't be affected. It uses the Foreground property from the Control base class... So be sure to test it out with all possible child element types.